# Hamburger and drop down not showing in mobile with Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching the boards here and nothing seems to cover what could be wrong. My navbar is all well and good but no hamburger or menu shows up when I go mobile.   I've tried changing combinations and implementing different collapse names, but to no avail.  Any ideas?  Here's my code:

```
     <header class="navbar navbar-custom" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
   </div>
   <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pages">
                <li class="page"><a href="item1.html">item1</a></li>
                <li class="page"><a href="item2.html">item2</a></li>
                <li class="page"><a href="item3.html">item3</a></li>
                <li class="page hidden-xs"><a href="item1.html"><img id="nav-brand" src="images/nav-logo1.png" width="120" alt="logo description"></a></li>
                <li class="page"><a href="item4.html">item4</a></li>
                <li class="page"><a href="item5.html">item5</a></li>
                <li class="page"><a href="item6.html">item6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you included the proper files?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the meta tag in your head section

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Also your Nav tag is not closing after the ul element. Check your tag closures

I think the `</div>` after the `</ul>` has to be replaced

Answer (score 1):

In the original code, there's a div that closes the nav. That happened when I formatted for this site. In the original, it is closed by a nav tag.  I forgot to include the header sets. Here they are:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8633c13aa3.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should check the horizontal scroll when u minimize the screen.that is one of the reason when your content in not fully responsive and when u minimize the screen the scroll appears horizontally and the hamburger icon not appear...

first of all remove all content expect the navigation on your page and then minimize the screen .and if problem still appers then you sould also check that your background color and color are change or not..

Comment: I tried that.  Could you explain what you mean about the background color changing?